# Outllok 2010 & 2013 email getting stuck in outbox, not making it to sent box

Tags: email, outlook

I have been unable to find similar reported issues that I am experiencing or maybe I just am not phrasing it properly.

I have an instance of WIN8 w/ office 2013 and WIN7 w/ office200, I access them through my VM. On both instances I am experiencing an intermittent problem that I can not always replicate the problem. But it seems that after  about 10 minutes of use maybe more maybe less, when I write and send emails they are sometimes getting stuck in my "Outbox" folder. I have tried pressing the send and reverie button, it looks like everything ran fine but the mail still shows up in my outbox rather than my sent box. When I restart the application, you sill see the message updating outlook,once it is completed you see the emails go from the outbox to sent. This happens in both instances of 2007 and 2010, is there a setting or something like that I am missing?.Because sometime when you open outllok and the first you do is send an email and everything works fin!

Comment: If this is about programming please clarify. If not, you may be able to get help on Super User http://superuser.com/tour. Consider deleting this question. As it stands now it can only gather downvotes which impacts your ability to ask questions. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well-known issue. Take a look at the similar pages:

- [How to troubleshoot mail stuck in the Outbox](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182572)
- [How to troubleshoot e-mail messages that are stuck in your Outbox](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262052)
- [Email stuck in the Outbox in Outlook 2010 / 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2663435)